# addOnScrollListener Not working (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating a recyclerview pagination on my app but suddenly the addOnScrollListener is not working. How can I fix this? thank you for any help.

this is my code

```
  private void initView(){
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(list);
        myAdapter.setOnClickListener((data, position) -> {
            mydata = data;
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                isLoading = true;
                EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.setLoading(true);
                Map<String, Object> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
                queryMap.put("page",page);
                queryMap.put("item_count","20");
           myApiHelper.getDataUser(mytoken,id,queryMap);
                Log.d("log0","page "+page);
                Log.d("log0","totalItemsCount "+totalItemsCount);
                Log.d("log0","arrayList.size "+list.size());
                Log.d("log0","totalPages "+totalPages);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working ? It crash ? (then could you add the stacktrace). It does not behave as expected ? (then could you describe the actual behaviour and the expected one)

Comment: Nope, it not crash. When I scroll the recyclerview its not working, the onLoadMore is not triggering.

Comment: the log is not printing

Comment: how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Approximately it should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

    int pastVisibleItems = 0, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager =
            (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
    firstVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
    if(firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
        pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
    }

    if (loading) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
            loading = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "LOAD NEXT ITEM");

            loadMoreItem();
        }
    }
}
```